# including Multiple headers in Code::Blocks error

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have a project in eclipse which runs with no problem ,however when I make this project in `Code::Blocks` it gives me a header error:

```
error: websocketpp/config/core.hpp: No such file or directory
```

http://i57.tinypic.com/157jgww.jpg

it opens one of the Websocket headers, which calls another header and if I change this line

```
websocketpp/config/core.hpp
```

to this

```
"core.hpp"
```

this line gives no more error! But there are lots of includes lines and this is not a correct way to solve this error.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Set the right include paths?

Comment: Yes , although I have included headers in project , I've added the path in Build Options>Search directories>Compiler>Websocketpp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the location of the file `core.hpp` is, say, `/blah1/blah2/websocketpp/config/core.hpp`, then add `/blah1/blah2` to the compiler path instead of `/blah1/blah2/websocketpp`.